# how can create two navbar' with out any space between two navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to design a web page with 'bootstarp' (not responsive) ,like first image link . but I designed second image link.
I need put Logo top of two 'navbar' , and I don't need any space between two 'navbar' like second Image.
sorry for bad English.
please help me.

[first Image](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-09/20763896099356487735.jpg)

[second Image](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-09/01335562827206675586.png)

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  navBack" role="navigation">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=""><a href="#">login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">buy<img src="img/00.png"
                    class="pull-left" style="width: 30px" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default background-color clear " role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse clear " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <img class="pull-right" src="img/buy100-30.jpg" />
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class=""><a href="#">some text</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">some text</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group" style="position: absolute">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-warning border-radius">search</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-right border-radius"
                        placeholder="search " style="width: 350px" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

 <style>
    .direction {
        direction: rtl;
    }

    .navBack {
        background-image: url("img/stripe.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-x repeat-y;
    }

    .background-color {
        background-color: #4d4246;
    }

    .border-radius {
        border-radius: 0;
    }


    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>
```

I wrote only these css and another css are from bootstrap3

Comment: if you post the css i will update the answer now itself

Comment: yup CSS would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap navbars have a 20px bottom margin which is where your gap is coming from.

Add this to your CSS to remove the margin form all navbars:

```
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

It's probably better to add a class to your first navbar and only remove the margin from that to avoid unexpected results elsewhere.

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/vCPakV6NZt)

Comment: I know it's true , but it doesn't work for me. why? help me :(

Comment: In your question you are using `navbar-fixed-top` but it does not look as though you are in your screenshot. Are you using a fixed navbar? Or normal?

Comment: no I use this <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-no-margin navBack navbar-no-margin" role="navigation"  style="position:absolute ;top:0 ; left:0 ;">

Comment: You should probably remove `style="position:absolute ;top:0 ; left:0 ;"`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
.navbar {
    margin: 0;// if you dont need any margins
}


.navbar {
    margin: 0 auto;//add this to append parent tag
}
```